# Tomcat Cluster problem -session timeed out -in load balancing

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, session-timeout

I am having two tomcat instances in cluster mode;load-balancing enabled with apache using mod_jk. What i see is - load balancing is happening properly but the session doesn't get replicated. In case one node goes down then users attached to that node get session time out.

I have the default deltamanager setting also the sticky_session flag is set to 1 in workers properties file.

Could somebody help me to diagnose this problem.

Thanks in advance.
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

When I have previously run into this and most other issues with Tomcat clustering it was a mis-configuration issue.

The default ports that need to be open are:
45564
4000

Also check that your server.xml configuration lists the IP of the server instead of "auto". We also ran into issues with Tomcat only binding to the localhost/127.0.0.1 and not the assigned IP address.